# How to set up a unit test for spring data with service and repository?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I have checked many SO comments and the docs for spring data and unit testing but I cant get this to work and I dont know why its not working.

I have a junit test class that looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class DealServiceTest {

    @Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration {

        // this bean will be injected into the OrderServiceTest class
        @Bean
        public DealService orderService() {
            DealService dealService = new DealService();
            // set properties, etc.
            return dealService;
        }

        @Bean
        public EmployeeService employeeService(){
            EmployeeService employeeService = new EmployeeService();
            return employeeService;
        }

    }

    @Autowired
    DealService dealService;

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeeService;

    @Test
    public void createDeal() throws ServiceException {
        Employee employee = new Employee("Daniel", "tuttle", "danielptm@me.com", "dannyboy", "secret password", 23.234, 23.23);
        Deal d = dealService.createDeal("ADSF/ADSF/cat.jpg", "A title goes here", "A deal description", 23.22, "Name of business", 23.23,23.23, employee, "USA" );
        Assert.assertNotNull(d);

    }
```

}

And then I have my service class that looks like this

```
@Service
public class DealService {

    @Autowired
    private DealRepository dealRepository;

    public Deal createDeal(String image, String title, String description, double distance, String location, double targetLat, double targetLong, Employee employee, String country) throws ServiceException {
        Deal deal = new Deal(image, title, description, distance, location, targetLat, targetLong, employee, country);
        try {
            return dealRepository.save(deal);
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new ServiceException("Could not create a deal: "+deal.toString(), e);
        }
    }

    public Deal updateDeal(Deal d) throws ServiceException {
        try{
            return dealRepository.save(d);
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new ServiceException("Could not update deal at this time: "+d.toString(),e);
        }
    }

    public List<Deal> getAllDealsForEmployeeId(Employee employee) throws ServiceException {
        try{
            return dealRepository.getAllDealsBy_employeeId(employee.getId());
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new ServiceException("Could not get deals for employee: "+employee.getId(), e);
        }
    }

}
```

And then my repository:

*/

```
public interface DealRepository extends CrudRepository<Deal, Long>{

    public List<Deal> getDealsBy_country(String country);

    public List<Deal> getAllDealsBy_employeeId(Long id);

}
```

My config file looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.globati.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class InfrastructureConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DatabaseProject");
        config.setUsername("awesome");
        config.setPassword("database");
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

//  @Bean
//  public DataSource derbyDataSource(){
//      HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
//      config.setDriverClassName("jdbc:derby:memory:dataSource");
//      config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/myDB;create=true");
//      config.setUsername("awesome");
//      config.setPassword("database");
//
//      return new HikariDataSource(config);
//
//  }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory factory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource()); //Get data source config here!
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.globati.model");

        return factory;
    }
}
```

But I get this error.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext ...
>
> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean found for dependency
>   [com.globati.repository.DealRepository]: expected at least 1 bean
>   which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Any suggestions for how I can successfully do unit testing with spring data, junit and with my service and repositories would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you look at stack trace it seems like problem is with EmployeeService (if it uses EmployeeRepository) and not with DealService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a repository bean to be injected,

- You need to enable Repositories, using one of the spring-data annotations. So add `@Enable*Repositories` to your configuration class
- You also need dB factories and other related beans configured. I am using Mongo and I have mongoDbFactory bean configured
- And for the most part your test configuration should look like your main configuration except for unnecessary bean replaced by mock implementations

**UPDATE**
Here is my code (sorry mine is in mongo, I think you can relate)

```
@Configuration
@WebAppConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.amanu.csa",
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = WebConfig.class))
@EnableMongoRepositories(repositoryImplementationPostfix = "CustomImpl")
class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        return new MongoClient("localhost")
    }

    @Bean
    MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongo(), "csa_test")
    }

    @Bean
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        MongoTemplate template = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory())
        template.setWriteResultChecking(WriteResultChecking.EXCEPTION)
        return template
    }
}
```

That is my test config file... As you can see it explicitly excludes my main configuration file.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
class OrganizationServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    OrganizationService organizationService

     @Test
    void testRegister() {
        def org = new Organization()
        //...
        organizationService.register(org)
        // ...
    }
```

And that is my test class. It refers to the test config, and I recommend using named config classes. You can put common options onto a super class and extend those and use them for your tests.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. A code example would be great because I think I have done what you suggest but it does not work still.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add

```
@ActiveProfiles("your spring profile")
```

In addition I would suggest to use an embedded test db like flapdoodle (https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo)

Answer (score 0):

You could either :

- Mock your repository methods ([Using Mockito for example](http://site.mockito.org/)))
- Using an embedded database for your unit tests

Comment: Ok, is it necessary to use an embedded database such as derby opposed to a mysql?

Comment: It is if you use a continuous integration solution as Jenkins which may not have a database installed